# How do I implement a nested object whose type changes according to the generic?

Tags: typescript

I want to define data according to the structure that defines the type.

```
type Keys = {
  A: 'a';
  B: 'b';
};

type DynamicData = {
  base: {
    one: 'baseType';
  };
  A: {
    a: {
      one: 'one';
    };
  };
  B: {
    b: {
      one: 1;
    };
  };
};

type Auto = {
  [T in keyof Keys]: {
    [K in Keys[T]]: DynamicData[T][K];  // Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'DynamicData[T]'
  };
};

type Generic<T extends keyof Keys = undefined, S extends Keys[T] = undefined> = T extends keyof Keys
  ? S extends Keys[T]
    ? DynamicData[T][S] // Type 'S' cannot be used to index type 'DynamicData[T]'
    : DynamicData['base']
  : DynamicData['base'];
```

If I ignore the error and add two arguments to the generic, it seems to work normally.

If there are no generic arguments, I want it to output the default value, but that doesn't work.

```
const show: Generic<'B', 'b'> = {
  one: 1,
};

const show: Generic = {
  one: 1, // No error output
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looking at [this playground link with your code pasted into it](https://tsplay.dev/NB1rDw). There are quite a few errors you don't seem to be asking about which distract from the question (merely saying "if I ignore the error" doesn't help that), as well as an error where you say "no error output".  Please [edit] the question to clarify what you're looking for exactly ("the default value" is unspecific) and how it differs from what you got ("that doesn't work" is also not sufficient).  Right now I can't tell if your code is a [mre]; could you help?